# Can't figure out why my loop wont exit and print a the right time

Tags: python-3.x

Write a while loop that calculates the product of the integers from 1 to 20, but which stops after the accumulated product exceeds 1 billion (1000000000). Print the value of your calculated product afterward.

Hint: You'll find the break statement handy for this challenge, and you'll probably want to accumulate your product by doing something like this: product *= i. That means you'll need to initialize your product accumulator to 1, as you've shown below.

see code

```
i = 1
product = 1

while i<21:
    product *= i
    i += 1

    if product > 1000000000000:
        break

print(product)
```

I want the loop to exit once the product exceeds 1 billion and print that number right now the out put is 1307674368000 but know it should be 6227020800.

Comment: Your code is correct but your condition has too many zeros! Count again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop currently exits at one trillion. Change that to one billion and the output is as expected:

```
i = 1
product = 1

while i < 21:
    product *= i
    i += 1
    if product > 1000000000:
        break

print(product)
```

## Output

```
6227020800
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you used 1000000000000 instead of 1000000000. To prevent such problems, use underscore:

```
if product > 1_000_000_000:
    break
```